# Getting 404 (not found) error for routes defined in config/routes.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, sails.js

Just learning sails with node and have been running into an issue, I have all of my views created and my user controller, but when I click sign up, it takes me to `localhost/signup` and 404s me. Alternatively, going to `/user`, `/login`, `/quiz` all end in 404s as well.

This is my views folder contents:

```
- 403.ejs
- 404.ejs
- 500.ejs
- homepage.ejs
- index.ejs
- layout.ejs
- quiz.ejs
```

My signup method should be routing me to `quiz.ejs`, but just kind of breaks. These are my custom routes:

```
module.exports.routes = {
    // HTML Views
    '/': { view: 'index' },
    '/quiz': { view: 'quiz' },

    // Endpoints
    'post /login': 'UserController.login',
    'post /signup': 'UserController.signup',
    '/logout': 'UserController.logout',
};
```

These routes are referencing my UserController.js which have a `login`, `logout` and `signup` function, here are those functions, here is my `sign up` function:

```
    signup: function (req, res) {

        // Attempt to signup a user using the provided parameters
        User.signup({
            name: req.param('name'),
            email: req.param('email'),
            password: req.param('password'),
            avatar: req.param('avatar'),
        }, function (err, user) {
            // res.negotiate() will determine if this is a validation error
            // or some kind of unexpected server error, then call `res.badRequest()`
            // or `res.serverError()` accordingly.
            if (err) return res.negotiate(err);

            // Go ahead and log this user in as well.
            // We do this by "remembering" the user in the session.
            // Subsequent requests from this user agent will have `req.session.me` set.
            req.session.me = user.id;
            req.session.name = user.name;


            // If this is not an HTML-wanting browser, e.g. AJAX/sockets/cURL/etc.,
            // send a 200 response letting the user agent know the signup was successful.
            if (req.wantsJSON) {
                return res.ok('Signup successful!');
            }

            // Otherwise if this is an HTML-wanting browser, redirect to /welcome.
            return res.redirect('/quiz');
        });
    }
```

As you can see, my return is set to `/quiz`, but it doesn't seem to fire. Edit: on click, I am receiving this console error as well:

> POST http://localhost:1337/signup 404 (Not Found)

What could be causing this?

Comment: Sounds like the action may not be getting registered.  Try starting Sails with `sails lift --verbose` to see if there are any warnings.  Also, where is your `UserController.js` file saved?

Comment: @sgress454 Appreciate the response, I ended up solving this when I noticed sublime didn't accept my save of changing my file name from `usercontroller.js` to `UserController.js`

Comment: Ah, good to know.  Want to post your solution so that we can mark this as answered?

Comment: @sgress454 Will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling and looking over my files, I realized that Sublime did not save my changes to the file name. I was trying to reference `UserController.js` when it was actually named `usercontroller.js`, changing this got everything working smoothly again!